# Какой язык программирования самый перспективный для разработки мобильных приложений?

Tags: c#, android, java

Актуален ли сейчас c# или намного лучше джава? Как вы относитесь к моно?

Comment: "на много" - слитно =)  Для начала русский бы неплохо выучить, чтобы читателям было просто вас понять.

Comment: Английский. В ближайшем обозримом будущем всегда можно будет, воспользовавшись им, нанять разработчиков.

Все остальное — тлен. Несколько лет и извольте получить новый *тренд*, менеджерам за тишину деньги не платят.

Comment: Тема [уже обсуждалась](http://hashcode.ru/questions/139432/windowsphone7-windows-phone-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-android) - закрываю как явный дубль темы: http://hashcode.ru/questions/139432/windowsphone7-windows-phone-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-android

Answer (score 6):

Я бы сказал, что это C#, т.к. **Xamarin** предоставляет средства, хоть и не бесплатные, для разработки на нем нативных приложений под iOS и Android, такие как **Monodroid** и **Monotouch**. И конечно возможность писать на C# под WP8 существует из коробки.
Таким образом, на С# можно написать мобильные приложения с незначительными изменениями кода сразу для 3-х платформ: Android, iOS и Windows Phone 8.

А если вы хотите писать игры для мобильных платформ, то существует, к примеру **Unity3d**, скрипты в котором опять же пишутся на C#(или JS) и компилировать их можно тоже сразу для всех платформ.

Comment: Согласен! C# самый перспективный из того что есть.

Comment: @GenchiK из того, что есть -- это из C# и java? Или C#, F#, java, scala? или из чего?

Comment: из всех языков которые есть под мобильные платформы, C++, Java, JavaSript, Python

Answer (score 5):

Перспективный язык - бесполезное понятие. Если вопрос только в том, какой язык (и фреймворк) начинать изучать, стоит сначала четко сформулировать задачу, а затем смотреть, насколько качественно она будет решаться с применением C# или Java.
Mono - штука хорошая, даже [в MSVS можно под нее писать](http://habrahabr.ru/post/73810/).

Comment: Осталось дождаться проекта stereo (который должен быть намного лучше, чем mono. Про quadro и говорить нечего)

Comment: >> Осталось дождаться проекта stereo

Какой такой stereo? Зачем нужен? Где почитать?

Comment: думаю, это была игра слов:)

Comment: Да, это разные системы воспроизведения звуков -- моно, стерео, квадро. Хотя аналогичные хохмы время от времени случаются. more -- less, motif -- lesstif и т.д. Так что нельзя исключать существование какого-нибудь stereo.

Answer (score 3):

Хм, как по мне, то для разработки мобильных приложений лучше чем java не найти, ну конечно если ты не собираешься программить под iphone.

Answer (score 3):

[phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

хватит знаний html5 и javascript

работает на всех платформах

p.s. это так для общего развития

Comment: и по старой традиции html по разному работает на разных платформах (читай - в разных движках браузера). Сам на нем не кодил, но пару раз участвовал в установке проги на фонгеп, накоженный под андроид, на айось, пришлось дополнительно править код. Работали ли эти правки на изначальном устройстве с андроидом не знаю

Comment: гавно этот фонгеп, пол года пишу на нем приложения, одни убытки от него, полного доступа к системе не имеет, сервис на нем не создашь да и джаваскрипт сам по себе тупой и тормазнутый... Лучше уж нативное приложение написать чем на фонгепе ковыряться..

Answer (score 3):

> актуален ли сейчас c#

да

> или на много лучше джава?

и да и нет. Все сильно зависит от задач. На windows платформе я бы отдал предпочтение C#, на других -  java.

> Как вы относитесь к моно?

точно так же, как и к .NET. Место на диске требует только:) Есть несколько программ, которым оно нужно. Но по факту предпочел бы отказаться от него. У меня ещё не было ни одной задачи, где .NET/Mono были бы лучше, чем другие технологии, которые я использую.

Comment: >> Место на диске требует только:) 

А что, Java уже без своего толстого фреймворка работает?
MSVC++ Redistributable Package тоже место на диске занимает, да.
Мы живем в то время, когда дисковое пространство измеряется сотнями гигабайт, а ты будто продолжаешь смотреть на это из далекого 95 года.

Comment: Говорить о том, что у нас сейчас сотни гигов диски и оправдывать этим все подряд - очень плохая затея.

Чем больше программа, тем больше она использует ресурсов (в том числе и нагревания атмосферы и потребление электроэнергии), что только ускорит "глобальное потепление" (с) в будущем.

Имею опыт в переписывании с java на с++ проекта, который меньше чем за сутки выедал всю оперативку в 18 гигабайт и 50 гигабайт свопа. Проект активно профилировали, исследовали, но не справились. С++ версия работает месяцами и больше гигабайта оперативки не занимает.

Comment: Ну java на своём боевом счету имеет уникальное достижение -- инсталлятор для Oracle WinNT. Oracle'у хватало 64M RAM, а вот инсталлятору -- маловато было.

Comment: Управление памятью в Java - вообще отдельная история. Толстый фреймворк - это замечательная штука, благодаря которой один и тот же код не дублируется во всех приложениях. А брать частное утверждение и экстраполировать его на общий случай - тоже плохая затея, да.

>> з.ы. я с Вами пиво не пил, на ты не переходил.

Тю блин, как все сурьезно-то. Точно из 95 года. Сообщаю, что в интернете, как правило, не обращаются "на Вы" и не называют по имени-отчеству. Особенно среди программеров.

Comment: @Flammable

     Сообщаю, что в интернете, как правило, не обращаются "на Вы" и не называют по имени-отчеству.

Где это правило можно прочитать?

Comment: Даже не знаю, почему-то повелось так везде. Хотя отдельные персоны считают, что если их (или они сами кого-то) не называют на Вы и с большой буквы, то это оскорбляет и унижает их достоинство. Особенно любопытны случаи, когда такие персоны делают кучу орфографических ошибок (вроде не относится к этому случаю :) ).
Нет, я, конечно, не против; как говорится, каждый сходит с ума по-своему.

Comment: @Flammable. Значит, "как правило" -- это результат личных наблюдений. Fixed.

Comment: @alexlz, где написано, что в интернете принято к каждому обращаться на Вы?
Есть такая штука как Сетевой этикет, в котором указано, что допускается любая форма обращения, если правилами конкретного сообщества не указано иное.

Comment: Напряг гугла, получил http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%82. Не понял. Там сказано, что данный вопрос относится к эмоционально-психологической категории. Но где расписано, следует выбирать "Ты" или "Вы" -- не указано. Ссылка на rfc1855 не катит, в английском "Вы" с большой буквы не пишется. Есть ссылка на сеть, основанную нью-йоркскими педерастами (fido), но нет ссылки на конкретный документ...

Comment: Насколько помню, в каких-то местных правилах (сходу не нашел где именно) ХэшКод просил участников обращаться друг к друг на "Вы".

Вот, собственно, и все.

Answer (score 0):

Выброшу тезис. Зачем использовать традиционные средства?

Необходима поддержка под две основные платформы - android и ios.

И тут проблема - первый требует Java, второй - object-c.

Приходиться либо переписывать код, либо искать общие интерпретаторы.

Здесь выбор падает на PhoneGap. Эта штука предлагает использовать HTML/JS.

Почему именно html/js? Ответ прост. С выходом HTML5 все считают эту пару ПЕРСПЕКТИВНОЙ. Да потому что html/js просты, легки, удобны и функциональны. Плюс кроссплатформены

Comment: Учитывая, что дизайн приложений на android и iOS все таки отличается, то все равно придется делать два разных приложения. Плюс идеология у платформ местами сильно отличается. PhoneGap скрывает это ценой уменьшения возможностей.

Для helloword'a - хорошо, для более-менее нормального приложения - нет.

Comment: +1, уже выше отписал - даже и без приведения к стандартному внешнему виду для платформы работает не одинаково, использовать стоит с осторожностью

Answer (score 0):

Я считаю самым перспективным языком для разработки мобильных приложений - чистый "C", ну и C#.
Код написаный на С легко переноситься на iOS, Android, BB10.
В iOS достаточно написать на objective-c обертку для вашего С кода. И этот-же код легко перенести на Android.NDK. BB10 написан на C/C++ под qnx. Мало-того, такое решение лучше всего подходит для разработки под OpenGLES.

Comment: А под blackberry там разве не порт qt? Он же есть и под андроид в бете, и под айось (правда, тут вообще только proof of concept вроде). На С вроде есть еще http://www.mosync.com/, но его я не щупал, да и у Делфи вроде появилась поддержка айоси.

Comment: Порт qt под bb это cascades. Я говорю про нативный код. То, что можно писать на чистом С под xcode,  android.ndk, bb10sdk в нативной среде. Без использования сторонних библиотек.
Я просто предлагаю подойти к вопросу с другой стороны. Вместо того, чтобы ждать когда кто-то НАПИШЕТ порт на HTML, javascript, и т.д., лучше писать на том, чем эти технологии базируются. На общем знаменателе - языке C.

Comment: можно конечно и самому писать на нативном коде, но, боюсь, из-за разного апи получится три разных приложения, хотя и на одном языке (кстати, плюсы тоже вроде покатят, по крайней мере на iOS они работают из коробки, на андроид сдк скорее всего тоже). Хотя просто перекомпилить все равно скорее всего не выйдет - управление на устройствах тоже разное

Comment: Чистый Си? И чем же он перспективен?

Comment: "из-за разного апи получится три разных "
Для каждой платформы достаточно написать промежуточные классы, чтобы подвести разные апи к общему знаменателю.
Согласен, что по сути получиться три разных приложения. Правда они пишутся всего один раз. А переносимая логика ( "Модель" ) приложения у всех будет общая.

Comment: и мы получаем собственный фреймворк аля кьют, или мосинк, или wxWidgets, а затраты для одного человека или небольшой группы людей скорее всего переплюнут построение трех отдельных приложений с портированием логики на апи конкретной платформы

Comment: "Чистый Си? И чем же он перспективен?"

А на чем по вашему написаны все эти ваши phoneGap-ы? Я не утверждаю что иммено на С, я говорю о том что вы можете добиться желаемого результата без сторонних кроссплатформенных sdk, с меньшим количеством головной боли. И главное, не зависеть от кода, который будет посредником, в котором нету исходников, и в котором нету возможности реализовать все особенности каждой платформы.

Согласитесь, было-бы хорошо, если ваше приложение реализовало все сильные стороны каждой мобильной платформы, а не только общие понятия между ними

Comment: "А на чем по вашему написаны все эти ваши phoneGap-ы?"
На основном языке платформы он написан, для iOs это obj-c, на андройде скорее всего задействованна java и т.п.

Comment: "На основном языке платформы он написан, "
Я с вами согласен. Весь мой посыл был в том, что не обязательно использовать кроссплатформенные sdk.

Для написания приложений под iOS лучше использовать obj-c, для android java. И это правильно. 
Но что-же делать, если нам нужны приложения под iOS и под android? Можно писать их отдельно. Это хороший путь. Но мне, как программисту хочется упростить процесс.

Comment: Но мне, как программисту хочется упростить этот процесс. Мне нравиться возможность писать ПО под android на ndk. И поддержка C в xcode. А также использования языка С как основного в bb10. Только исходя из этого я сделал такое заключение.